# How to display images with AJAX request - Django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I am trying to build a search suggestion dropdown with AJAX but I dont know how to get my images to be displayed after ajax request in **template**
Here is the code:

**html**

```js
<form class="search" method='get'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.q }}
    <button type="submit">
         <i style="padding-top: 0.125rem; font-size: 1.75rem;" class="material-icons">search</i></button>
</form>
---
<script>
        $(document).on('keyup', '#id_q', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var results = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{% url "search" %}',
                data: {
                    ss: $('#id_q').val(),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}',
                    action: 'post'
                },
                success: function (json) {
                    $.each(JSON.parse(json.search_string), function (i, item) {

                        results.push(
                            `<div onclick="window.location.href='${item.fields.slug}'" class="anime"> \
                                <div class="background-search"> \
                                    <img src="${item.fields.image.url}" alt=""> \
                                    <div class="cover"></div> \
                                    <div class="anime-data"> \
                                        <img src="${item.fields.icon}" alt=""> \
                                        <div class="anime-info"> \
                                            <div class="data"> \
                                                <h3>${item.fields.title_english}</h3> \
                                                <div class="p">${item.fields.description}</div> \
                                            </div> \
                                            <div class="about"> \
                                                <span>Started:${item.fields.time_and_date_started}</span> \
                                                <span>Rating:${item.fields.rating}</span> \
                                            </div> \
                                        </div> \
                                    </div> \
                                </div> \
                            </div>`);

                    })

                    document.getElementById("anime-list-id").innerHTML = results;
                },
                error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {}
            });
        })
    </script>
```

I tried multiple ideas but none worked

- `${item.fields.image.url}`
- `${item.fields.image}`
- `${item.fields.image.src}`

The other fields are working but not the icon / image

**views.py**

```py
def search(request):
    form = SearchForm()
    
    if request.POST.get('action') == 'post':
        search_string = str(request.POST.get('ss'))

        if search_string is not None:
            search_string = Anime.objects.filter(title_english__icontains=search_string)[:7]

        data = serializers.serialize('json', list(search_string), fields=('id', 'title_english', 'description', 'image', 'icon', 'rating', 'time_and_date_started', 'slug'))

        return JsonResponse({'search_string':data})

    return render(request, 'search/search.html', {'form': form})
```

This is the result:

[image]

And this is how it should look like:
[image]

Any ideas you think may be causing the problem?

Comment: Hi, did you check if `${item.fields.image.url}` showing correct value for image ?

Comment: Hello, I checked agian what is the difference in html with `${item.fields.image.url}` and `${item.fields.image}`.This are the results:
`item.fields.image.url` in src is says **undefined**
`item.fields.image` in src is says **anime/image/opm2_N1i0UXm.jpg**
but it still doesnt work, probably because the file is in media - > media/anime/image/opm2_N1i0UXm.jpg.  Any idea? @Swati

Comment: I added **/media/** in front of `${item.fields.image}` and now it works <img src="/media/${item.fields.image}" alt="">. Thank you very much